# Define a piecewise function with three variables

Tags: function, matlab, piecewise

I am trying to define a function in MATLAB according to the following conditions:

```
If t<0 
     f(t,x,y)=t*(x/y)+1.
else
     f(t,x,y)=-t*(x/y)+1.
end
```

I found a way to define a piecewise function in one variable, but here I have three variables. Is there a way to define such a function in MATLAB?

Comment: I'm confused as to why you need a piecewise function for this. Surely the function `f(t,x,y) = -abs(t) * (x/y) + 1` satisfies the conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following creates an [anonymous function](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f4-70115.html) with the equation you describe above

```
f = @(t,x,y) -abs(t) * (x/y) + 1;
```

Then you can use it like a normal function:

```
y = f(tData,xData,yData);
```

If it's more complicated than that, then it needs to be a [sub-function](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f4-70666.html), [nested function](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f4-39683.html) or [private function](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f4-70335.html).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you need to do 3 `if`s.
I will show you how to do it for 2 variables:

```
If t<0 
  if x<0
     %Case 1
  else
     %Case 2           
  end
else
  if x<0
     %Case 3
  else
     %Case 4
  end

end
```

Alternatively, you can use 2^3=8 `if`-`elseif`s. Or, in 2 variables case - 2^2 = 4.

```
 if t<0 && x<0
     %Case 1      
 elseif t<0 && x>0
     %Case 2     
 elseif t>0 && x>0
     %Case 3
 else
     %Case 4
 end
```